# How to debug a failing CMD in docker which runs fine when started manually in the container?

Tags: docker

I package most of my code in docker containers to ensure a standalone, repeatable run.

I stumbled upon one case whee I do not understand why a specific container would not start.

The Dockerfile for that container is below. The general idea is to go for a two-stage build where a frontend would be built first and the compiled folder is reused in the container actually running afterwards. Two processes are started via `supervisord`

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /build
RUN npm install -g @quasar/cli
COPY front .
RUN npm install
RUN quasar build

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk -X http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev make jo py3-pip py3-wheel
RUN pip3 install pyyaml logbook multiping dnspython requests paho-mqtt arrow paramiko click dictdiffer supervisor flask flask_cors
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000
COPY --from=0 /build/dist dist
COPY ec2-xxcom.key .
COPY xx.openssh .
COPY config.yaml .
COPY homemonitor.py .
RUN ln -fs /app/results.json dist/statics/results.json
COPY supervisord.conf .
CMD supervisord -c /app/supervisord.conf
```

This builds and runs fine on my Windows 10 Docker Desktop. `supervisord` starts the processes from its configuration file.

In order to go in production, the repository is pushed to Gitlab and built though its CI/CD, ending up with an image pushed to my registry.

The `docker-compose` file for that service is

```
services:
  homemonitor:
    container_name: homemonitor
    image: myregistry.example.com/homemonitor:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /etc/docker/container-data/homemonitor:/app
    labels:
      - CADDY_ENABLE
version: '3'
```

Starting this image is not successful:

```
~ # docker-compose -f /etc/docker/docker-compose.d/homemonitor.yaml up
Creating homemonitor ... done
Attaching to homemonitor
homemonitor    | Error: could not find config file /app/supervisord.conf
homemonitor    | For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

When I manually reach that container, I can start the `CMD` command from the Dockerfile.

First staring the container and peeking at the contents:

```
~ # docker run --rm --name=homemonitor -it homemonitor ash
/app # ls
config.yaml                                             homemonitor.py                                          supervisord.log
dist                                                    xx.openssh
ec2-xxcom.key  supervisord.conf

/app # stat /app/supervisord.conf
  File: /app/supervisord.conf
  Size: 177             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 3ch/60d Inode: 22719869    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-06-17 13:51:52.000000000
Modify: 2020-06-17 13:51:52.000000000
Change: 2020-06-17 13:55:23.000000000
```

Than running `supervisord` by hand:

```
/app # supervisord -c /app/supervisord.conf
2020-06-17 14:34:07,250 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2020-06-17 14:34:07,253 INFO supervisord started with pid 9
2020-06-17 14:34:08,258 INFO spawned: 'gui' with pid 11
2020-06-17 14:34:08,261 INFO spawned: 'homemonitor' with pid 12
2020-06-17 14:34:08,845 DEBG 'homemonitor' stdout output:
2020-06-17 14:34:08,844 [homemonitor] INFO starting internet web server for results
(... supervisord continues ...)
```

So there is some kind of disconnect between the `CMD supervisord -c /app/supervisord.conf` in the `Dockerfile` and `supervisord -c /app/supervisord.conf` started manually from within the container. I do not know what this can be.

Comment: When you launch it using `docker-compose up`, what does the `docker-compose.yml` fragment look like?

Comment: @DavidMaze: I updated the question with the docker file

Comment: @DavidMaze ... and found what was wrong thanks to that: the mounted volume was in the way. I removed the mount form the config file and everything started. I will  put a detailed answer